# SQL Joining 3 Tables with same format

Tags: sql, join

Need help to get the total Val for each date! 
I currently have 3 tables each storing the same kind of data in the same format.

I need to arrive at a single table with the respective Val for each date.

```
CREATE TABLE table1(Date DATE, Val INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE table2(Date DATE, Val INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE table3(Date DATE, Val INTEGER);

INSERT INTO table1 values('2013-01-01', 4);
INSERT INTO table1 values('2013-01-02', 3);
INSERT INTO table1 values('2013-01-04', 2);

INSERT INTO table2 values('2013-01-01', 5);
INSERT INTO table2 values('2013-01-03', 4);
INSERT INTO table2 values('2013-01-04', 1);

INSERT INTO table3 values('2013-01-02', 3);
INSERT INTO table3 values('2013-01-03', 1);
INSERT INTO table3 values('2013-01-06', 8);
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT table1.Date, table2.Date, table3.Date, ISNULL(table1.Val,0) + ISNULL(table2.Val,0) + ISNULL(table3.Val,0) 
FROM table1
FULL JOIN table2 
ON table1.Date = table2.Date
FULL JOIN table3
ON table1.Date = table3.Date
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could `UNION ALL` the values from each table as a derived table and then `SUM(Val)` and `GROUP BY` over `Date` from that table:

```
SELECT Date, SUM(Val)
FROM (SELECT * FROM table1
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT * FROM table2
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT * FROM table3) v
GROUP BY Date
```

Output

```
Date        SUM(Val)
2013-01-01  9
2013-01-02  6
2013-01-03  5
2013-01-04  3
2013-01-06  8
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rdFNpYeARBG93rZYu8ha1i/0)

Answer (score 0):

MERGE can be used in this case. I created a new table called newtable and the data is merged into that table leaving the original tables intact. I changed the column name Date to Dait.

```
select * into newtable
from table1

merge newtable t1
using table2 t2
on t1.Dait = t2.Dait
when matched
then update set
t1.Val = t1.Val + t2.Val
when not matched
then insert (Dait, Val)
values(t2.Dait, t2.Val);

merge newtable t1
using table3 t3
on t1.Dait = t3.Dait
when matched
then update set
t1.Val = t1.Val + t3.Val
when not matched
then insert (Dait, Val)
values(t3.Dait, t3.Val);
```

Answer (score 0):

`FULL JOIN` should work if your tables don't have duplicate dates:

```
SELECT COALESCE(table1.Date, table2.Date, table3.Date) as date, 
       COALESCE(table1.Val, 0) + COALESCE(table2.Val, 0) + COALESCE(table3.Val, 0) 
FROM table1 FULL JOIN
     table2 
     ON table1.Date = table2.Date FULL JOIN
     table3
     ON table1.Date = table3.Date;
```

In many databases you can somewhat simplify this with the `USING` clause:

```
SELECT date, 
       COALESCE(table1.Val, 0) + COALESCE(table2.Val, 0) + COALESCE(table3.Val, 0) 
FROM table1 FULL JOIN
     table2 
     USING (Date)
     table3
     USING (Date);
```

Often, the `FULL JOIN` is going to perform better than `UNION ALL`/`GROUP BY`.  I do find the latter to be a bit simpler, because you don't have to worry about `NULL` values.